# Find max number used from a table by getting range of two numbers from another table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

Following image will show you that there're two tables, Ranges and items.
Ranges table will show you ranges from a min number to a max number. 
items table will show the numbers from those ranges that have been used. In other words, from each range some numbers are used and some are yet to be used. I want a query that will find the maximum number used in each given range.
For example, from the range 1 to 100, the max number that was used is 5. I want my result to show 5 as max number used. Similarly, second range should show 110 and third range should show null because none of the numbers has been used.

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9TDs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need a left outer join and aggregation:

```
select   r.frnumber, r.tonumber, max(i.rangenum) as maxnumused
from     ranges r left outer join items i
                  on i.rangenum between i.frunmber and i.tonumber
group by r.frnumber, r.tonumber
;
```